# Android linechart using achartengine Inside Fragment getting error

Tags: android

Hi This is my entire line chart code inside the fragment while i am running i am geeting null pointer exception at this below line:

```
chartContainer.addView(mChart);
```

My Java and Xml code are as fallows below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Heading"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code is:

```
public class LineChartFragment extends Fragment{

    private View mChart;

    private String[] mMonth = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb" , "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug" , "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        };

     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_chart, container, false);

        openChart();
        return view;
      }

     private void openChart(){
            int[] x = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
            int[] income = { 2000,2500,2700,3000,2800,3500,3700,3800};
            int[] expense = {2200, 2700, 2900, 2800, 2600, 3000, 3300, 3400 };

            // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
            XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Income");
            // Creating an  XYSeries for Expense
            XYSeries expenseSeries = new XYSeries("Expense");
            // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
            for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                incomeSeries.add(x[i], income[i]);
                expenseSeries.add(x[i],expense[i]);
            }

            // Creating a dataset to hold each series
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            // Adding Income Series to the dataset
            dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
            // Adding Expense Series to dataset
            dataset.addSeries(expenseSeries);

            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            incomeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
            XYSeriesRenderer expenseRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            expenseRenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            expenseRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            expenseRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
            expenseRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
            expenseRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Income vs Expense Chart");
            multiRenderer.setXTitle("Year 2012");
            multiRenderer.setYTitle("Amount in Dollars");
            multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
            for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, mMonth[i]);
            }

            // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
            // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
            // should be same
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
            multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(expenseRenderer);

            // Getting a reference to LinearLayout of the MainActivity Layout
            LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

            // Creating a Line Chart
            mChart = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity().getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);

            // Adding the Line Chart to the LinearLayout
            chartContainer.addView(mChart);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the full exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In openChart() method, you cannot use LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chart_container).

openChart() method is invoked in fragment.createView(Bundle b) method. At this point, activity does not load any view. So attached activity cannot find view inside the fragment. You should use this:

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_chart, container, false);

    openChart(view);
    return view;
  }

private void openChar(View v) {
    ....
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
    ...
}
```